# Pizzas? Slices of pizza?

Tags: prepositions

"I'd like to order a pizza" would mean only ordering one whole pizza. What should I say if I want to order more than one whole pizza?

"I'd like to order pizzas" sound a little weird.

And why is it okay to say "a pizza" when sometimes you have to say "a piece of pizza" or "a slice of pizza"

Comment: Pizza is no different than any other thing that you can purchase in multiples.  2 pizzas, 3 cars, 4 pencils.

Comment: ... except that 'half a pizza' is met with more frequently than 'half a car'.

Comment: Half a sandwich, one quarter of a watermelon, ...

Comment: Also see at EL&U, *[Countable ingredient pluralization](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/199473)* and *[Are frozen pizzas countable or uncountable?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121767)*.

Comment: Does "I'd like to order *some* pizzas" sound better. It seems more natural to me.

Answer (score 1):

Pizza is either sold as a whole (whether one purchases one or more) or sold by the slice.  When ordering delivered pizza from Dominoes, for example, one generally orders by the whole pizza. In this case you would say that you "ordered a pizza" or "ordered two (or three or however many) pizzas".  However, if you are actually in a place that sells pizza (ie. a mall, a supermarket, a restaurant) you might choose to order pizza by the slice. In this case you would say that you "ordered a slice" or multiple "slices" of pizza.

Comment: @auntlulu83 thank you! but why do people say "order a slice of pizza" when you are calling a pizza place and you want more than one pizza? i've never heard of "i want to order pizzas"

Comment: Pizza is tricky; it's like soup, not potatoes.

In British homes and US TV, I've only noticed 'pizza' or 'some pizza' 

For myself alone I might want 'a pizza' but other than that, number seems to come into it only at the level of varieties: 'I'd like to order some pizza, please. I'd like three Neapolitans, two Four Seasons and a (or one) Meat Feast.'

Personally, I've never heard 'some pizzas'. I wouldn't be surprised to hear 'three pizzas', but my ears would be as happy with 'three pizza'… prolly because 'three soups' will mean three the same. Different varieties will be 'Some soup'